# Receptacle island in freestanding wall

Tags: electrical

I have a freestanding half-wall in our garage. It's constructed of 2x4s and finished with drywall and is in a big L shape. It's technically mobile but heavy and doesn't move easily. I want to  get more outlets  in this wall for different chargers, a compressor, etc... I could get a large surge protector bar and mount it on the wall and connect it to a regular outlet but I was thinking that actual receptacles would give me more flexibility to design the space as I see fit.

So my question is the following: Can I install several receptacles along this wall, connected to each other through Romex but not connected to the house's electric panel? They would be powered by plugging an extension chord into one of the outlets (or using a hardwire conversion kit like they sell for garbage disposals. Is this against code or otherwise a terrible idea?

Comment: What you want is called an *inlet*...

Comment: Please no suicide cords...or think of them as "killing your children" cords if you are immune to the concept that YOU could ever screw up with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not part of the house then electrical codes for buildings don't apply to it.

That said you should meet or exceed the safety that electrical codes aim to provide.

It sounds like you are going to use a suicide cord to power it? **DON'T!** There is a reason they are called that.

Instead use an (singular) inlet or wire an power cord with plug into the structure, and make sure it's not a tripping hazard.

Comment: For powering a "mobile wall" the best option is typically going to be oulets in the ceiling and a power cord out (or inlet and extension cord) on the top of the wall - no tripping hazard.

Comment: I had never heard the term suicide cord before but after some google I understand why that'd be a bad idea. I'll try an inlet or hardwire a cable coming out of the top of the wall since there's an outlet just above it free next to the garage door opener. Thanks!